# How to add features to VectorLayerSource

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

as shown in `code2`, i have `keygridsAsGeoJSON` which contains coordinates of some features as geojson.in `code1` i am using `VectorTileLayer` and `VectorTileSource`.
the problem i have now is, i would like to add the features in the array `keygridsAsGeoJSON` to the `VectorTileSource`. i have googled some questions and articles, but unfortunately i could not find any example that demonstrate how to features can be added
to `VectorTileSource`

please let me know how can i achieve that.

**code1**:

```js
public visualisePolygonsAsMVTTilesOnMapWithColors(map,arrayOfPolygonsAsGeoJSON,fillColor,strokeColor,text){
    var features = [];
    arrayOfPolygonsAsGeoJSON.forEach(function(geojson) {
        var geometry = new GeoJSON().readGeometry(geojson, {
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()
        });
        features.push(new Feature(geometry));
      });

       var vectorTile = new VectorTileLayer({
        source: new VectorTileSource({
            format: new MVT({featureClass: Feature}),//<===================
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/mvtTilesForVectorLayerSource/{z}/{x}/{y}",
             features: features,
            featureClass: Feature //<===================
        }),
        style: new Style ({
                  fill: new Fill({
                      color: fillColor
                      }),
                      stroke: new Stroke({
                          color: strokeColor,                   
                          width: 3
                      })                                
                  })
      });
    return vectorTile;
    }
```

**code2**:

```js
    for (let i = 0;i <this.keygridsAsGeoJSON.length;i++) {
    
    if (this.areaOfCoveragePerWindowSegment[i] >= 0 && this.areaOfCoveragePerWindowSegment[i] <=9) {
        this.vectorLayer = this.openLayersAPIService.visualisePolygonsAsMVTTilesOnMapWithColors(this.map,[this.keygridsAsGeoJSON[i]['features'][0]['geometry']],AreaOfCoverageColorEnum2.WHITE_0,GridCellsColorEnum.RED,text)
        this.openLayersAPIService.addLayerToMap(this.map, this.vectorLayer)
    } else if(this.areaOfCoveragePerWindowSegment[i] >= 10 && this.areaOfCoveragePerWindowSegment[i] <=19) {
        this.vectorLayer = this.openLayersAPIService.visualisePolygonsAsMVTTilesOnMapWithColors(this.map,[this.keygridsAsGeoJSON[i]['features'][0]['geometry']],AreaOfCoverageColorEnum2.WHITE_1,GridCellsColorEnum.RED,text)
        this.openLayersAPIService.addLayerToMap(this.map, this.vectorLayer)
    } else if(this.areaOfCoveragePerWindowSegment[i] >= 20 && this.areaOfCoveragePerWindowSegment[i] <=29) {
        this.vectorLayer = this.openLayersAPIService.visualisePolygonsAsMVTTilesOnMapWithColors(this.map,[this.keygridsAsGeoJSON[i]['features'][0]['geometry']],AreaOfCoverageColorEnum2.WHITE_2,GridCellsColorEnum.RED,text)
        this.openLayersAPIService.addLayerToMap(this.map, this.vectorLayer)
        }
    }
```

Comment: A VectorTileSource does not have features, the features are in the tiles.

Comment: @Mike how can i add different color to every tile/feature?

Comment: Instead of the single style the layer would need a style function which styles features with an appropriate color.

Comment: @Mike would you please provide an example?

Comment: Something like https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/osm-vector-tiles.html where features are styled based on a property of the feature and optionally the view resolution.  You could calculate the tile the feature is in from its extent and the resolution.